# ASP.NET errors display my local development folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a inherited asp.net project. I never had this issue in others projects,so this is completly new for me.

In my web.config, I put that the errors in **customErrors mode="Off"**, and any error in the app is displayed on the screen.

The problem, is that the errors, displayed my develop local directory folder, when the site is published on other server...

Exameple:

```
ASP.NET Error
The connection of the server it's Close.
Error in C:\Develop\myProject\file.cs\MethodName() <- ?¿
```

Someone know what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: The local path also uses the local folder structure in my deployed projects; I don't thin that's an issue.  The real reason is figuring out why the connection to the server is closed.  Is that when connecting to the database, or processing a file through IO?

Comment: The Connection it's a example, my doubt it's 'for why the web site, published in a server, display my local develop folder in the errors, when are differents machine'

Comment: You should set customErrors to "ON" or "RemoteOnly". The latter would mean that anyone using the local machine will see the full error page, but any outside users won't. The less information outside users have about how your web application works, the better

Comment: I had detected that files with *.pdb extension (when compile in visual studio) will be able to provoque similar errors. This file musn't in bin folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The stack trace information shown when there is an error is fetched from the symbol information being produced during compilation. It is stored in the pdb-files. The symbol information refers to the location of the files during compilation. When deployed, the source .cs files are not even present on the target system, it just shows what's in the pdb.

This is completely normal behaviour and nothing to worry about.

As others have noted you should never leave customerrors off on a production server as the stack trace might reveal sensitive information.

Comment: I don't know the functionality of pdb files, it's a good point know about this. You are right in that 'the server show sensitive information', so i'm going to change the custom erros for On or RemoteOnly to hide this information to the possible user.

Answer (score 3):

By setting the customErrors mode="Off" will expose all exceptions thrown and exposes the errors thrown YSOD (Yellow Screen of Death)

If you want to hide these then set the option to "On" and then this will only show your custom error message/page. If you still need to see these error's then set it to RemoteOnly and this will show the YSOD on the local machine the site is deployed too but show the Custom Errors to everyone else.

As for showing your development folders this is because it is just using the information where the dll's were compiled.

Comment: It's very usefull that you comment. I'm going to work with toher type of error like On or RemoteOnly for prevent this messages. Thanks.